# Reactjs Build Showing blank page on apache server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache, react-router

I have created a build of my react app and deploy locally on apache server but it's showing a blank page. Every js, css and json file i am getting status 200 on my network tab of browser. any help is appreciated.Thank you.

[image: This is what i am getting on my network tab.]

This is my project package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "client_side",
  "homepage":".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "create-react-app": "^3.3.0",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jss": "^10.0.0",
    "material-table": "^1.54.1",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^2.4.7",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "md5-hash": "^1.0.1",
    "mdbreact": "^4.23.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-image": "^2.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "tubular-react": "^3.0.0-rc6",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.75",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "update": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is my html looks like:
[image: Below is my html looks like:]

Comment: Probably a problem with your code. You can tell some stuff is quite clearly loading, eg your favicon. Your html is loading because your page has a title

Comment: But using npm start my code is running fine and with static server it's running also but when i keep my build in my Apache document root it's showing blank page without any error in console.

Comment: Have you checked that the html element that your React app is trying to mount into is in the page?

Comment: @TKoL i have edited my question you can see my html as well. i am using PrivateRoute for routing.

Comment: Oh, you're using react-router!! Your route says 'localhost/build', which means your router base has to expect '/build' to be the root. Your issue is that your routes aren't rendering because none of them are set to render inside of /build, probably. That's my best guess

Comment: its solve my problem by add `"homepage": "."` in `Package.json` file